# Function Pointer Variable

Tags: c, function-pointers, qsort

I'm trying to create a function variable that point to a function that can be passed to the `qsort()` function, and I received an "*assignment type mismatch*" error when I tried to run the below codes.

```
int compareFunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   //codes
}

int main(void) {
  int *ptr;     //create a function pointer variable that point to compareFunc
  ptr = &compareFunc   //Initialize function pointer
  //codes
  return 0;
}
```

Could someone please tell me what I did wrong and explain what exactly is `const void *`?

Comment: int (*ptr)(const void *, const void *);

Comment: The man page for `qsort` shows the necessary way of declaration as part of `qsort()`'s declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Your declaration of pointer isn't a function pointer. It's just a regular pointer. It should be changed to declare a function pointer as follows.

```
int (*fptr) (const void *a, const void *b);
fptr = compareFunc;
```

For function pointers you never have to take the address explicitly using the & operator.

Also `const void *` means that the object/data pointed to by the pointer will not be modified in that function. So compiler will raise an error whenever you perform a write operation on the value the pointer points to.

Answer (score 1):

a function pointer is declared like this:

```
return_type (* variable_name)(params)
```

So in your case:

```
int (*cfptr)(const void * a, const void * b);
cfptr = compareFunc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `int *` is a type of object pointer, not a function pointer.

You can declare it as `int (*ptr)(const void *,const void *);`, or use `typedef` to simplify declaring function pointers:

```
typedef int (*comptr)(const void *a, const void *b);
int compareFunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   //codes
}

int main(void) {
  comptr ptr;     
  ptr = compareFunc;  
  //codes
  return 0;
}
```

Also note that instead of `ptr = &compareFunc;`, you can omit the `&` because the function name is converted to a function pointer automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of function pointer is incorrect. You are declaring a regular pointer.
The syntax of a function pointer declaration is :

```
<return_type> (* func_ptr_Variable_name) ( [params...] )
```

The function pointer should be :

```
int main(void){
   int (*ptr)(const void *,const void *);
   ptr = compareFunc;   //'&' is not needed here, function name is automatically converted to its address 
   ...
   return 0;
}
```

`const void *` simply means that the data pointed to by the `void *` pointer cannot be modified in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `man qsort` and you'll get (besides more):

> void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
>   **int(*compar)(const void *, const void *)**);

The emphasised part obviously has to be what you are looking for.